# How do I unlock a folder programatically in .Net?

Tags: .net, file, unlock

Basically I want to do what Unlocker does, only from code. I want to unlock all access to a folder (and files under it / subfolders), so I can subsequently delete it.

Comment: Do you mean this: http://ccollomb.free.fr/unlocker/ ? (Quick answer: you need to manipulate other processes and, probably, kernel data structures. This is only going to be made harder from .NET because .NET does not expose the APIs you need or allow device driver creation.)

Comment: Yes, that's the one. I was looking for a ready library / tool, possibly in unmanaged code but callable from .Net.

Answer (score 2):

You could just run Unlocker from your .Net app.

Comment: does Unlocker have a command line interface? Also, I found it not to work on 64 bit systems, I'm using LockHunter instead.

Comment: Yes, enter `Unlocker -H` for command line options.  Not sure about 64bit versions.